# const parameter lifespan in c++

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Consider this:

```
void l(Event const& e)
{
    KeyEvent& k = (KeyEvent&)e;
    std::cout<<k.action<<" "<<k.keyCode;
}

void k(Event const& e)
{
    KeyEvent& k = (KeyEvent&)e;
    std::cout<<k.action<<" "<<k.keyCode;
}

void t(Event const& e)
{
    l(e);
    k(e);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    t(KeyEvent(1,1));
}
```

When will the KeyEvent object be released from memory (is it after the scope ends or do I have to delete it)? And if that KeyEvent was actually passed around a lot more than that, can I be sure it will stay valid until the last function using it ends?

Comment: @ildjarn: Where's the undefined behavior?  That's behaving as a `static_cast`, which can downcast so long as the target type matches the runtime type of the object.  It does, so...

Comment: @Ben : It's also behaving as a `const_cast`, casting away the constness of a temporary.

Comment: @ildjarn: A temporary isn't `const`, so that's permitted too.

Comment: @Ben : A temporary can only bind to a const lvalue reference, and `e` is declared `Event const& e`, so yes, it _is_ const.

Comment: @ildjarn: A const reference can bind to a non-const object.  The temporary object is not const.  Besides, it's only modifying a const object using `const_cast` that's undefined behavior, the cast itself isn't.

Comment: @Ben : This is why comments are non-normative. ;-]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When will the KeyEvent object be released from memory (is it after the scope ends or do I have to delete it)?

It lives in the memory till the end of the full-expression which is the semicolon `;` of the statement:

```
t(KeyEvent(1,1));
                ^ end of the full-expression
```

By the way, you should `const` here (to avoid problem):

```
KeyEvent const& k = (KeyEvent const&)e; //added const on both side
```

Comment: hypoteticaly speaking, what kind of problem can I expect if I don't add the const to my cast?

Comment: @LukeB.: You may *modify* `k` in the function, and the compiler will not tell you that the object it is referring to, is a *const* object (when it is really const object, say when you pass a const object to the function).